# FormData not filled

Tags: jquery, html, form-data

There is something I can't understand in `FormData`.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var form_data = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    });
});
</script>

<body>

<form>
<input name='a' value='vala'/>
<input name='b' value='valb'/>
<input name='c' value='valc'/>
<input type='submit' value='sub'/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If I debug my code in Chrome, I expected to have the `form_data` object filled with my form input name and values.

But it seems to be always empty.

Where am I wrong?

[image: form_data empty?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormData` objects just behave differently from the typical `key => value` principle. They are meant to be added to and submitted eventually, not so much to be accessed/modified.

Chrome and Firefox seem to support reading from `FormData`. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through the form fields at all as you can just give the `form` element to the `FormData()` constructor. Try this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form_data = new FormData($('form')[0]);
      // ajax here...
});
```

Comment: I obtain the same result: if I debug the code with a point break after var form_data = new FormData($('form')[0]);, the object is still empty. I use jQuery 2.1

Comment: You cannot see the data inside a FormData object through inspection. If you send it in the AJAX request you should see the values sent in your server-side code